# GST and Per Diems.

Tags: canada, contractor, expenses, gst

As an independent contractor I charge GST for my services.  When I travel outside of my home area for work I charge a per diem to cover meals and incidental expenses that are not itemized.  It is a flat fee.  I include this as a line item on my invoice and report it as income to the CRA.  Am I required (should) I charge GST on my per diems as I do on my day rates and hourly rates?

Answer (score -1):

No, you charge GST only for your service and sales:

[GST/HST overview](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/menu-eng.html)

But anyway it's better to call Revenue or ask accountant for confirmation.